# Not able to show image (API setDrawIcons() not found error)

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart in our android project to show graph and it's very helpful. Using latest version 3.0.1 (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#usage)

I have some requirement to show image on top of BarEntry after some condition met. Same is working in example code downloaded.

```
    BarDataSet set1;
    set1.setDrawIcons(true);// Cannot resolve method 'setDrawIcons(boolen)
```

Why the above API is not part of library MPChartLib, am I missing something here?

Comment: I answered for my question and accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above problem got solved after integrating `MPChartLib` source code.

1. File -> Project Structure
2. click plus button to add New Module
3. Import Gradle Project
4. from Source directory:  and finish.

Comment: But this isn't actualy solution. Is it?
You just added a source code and got it resolved. But Using latest version 3.0.1, You'll still have the same issue if you wouldn't alternately import the source code

Comment: this is not actual solution, but this is how I imported and solved my specific problem. I didn't get this  sentence "You'll still have the same issue if you wouldn't alternately import the source code"

Answer (score 1):

The `setDrawIcons` method was added in 3.0.2. Change your Gradle option to read `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'`

Comment: let me check, if it works I will accept this answer.